# in web3 for wei take value at decimal?

Tags: go-ethereum, javascript

Thanks in Advance.

In web3.eth.util.**fromwei**, take value at what decimal?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3fromwei):

```
web3.fromWei(number, unit)
```

Example:

```
var value = web3.fromWei('21000000000000', 'finney');
console.log(value); // "0.021"
```